# Can't receive email. Email delayed. Problem with MX?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, mx-record

I'm trying to setup my domain name for my new windows 2008 server and everything has been working well so far except for one little thing :

When I send emails to my domain, I received email delayed message the day after. I'm pretty sure it's something about my MX. This is my configuration:

```
#   type    host    value   prior(MX)

1   A   @   
199.19.212.38
--
2   CNAME   www 
brainpad.org
--
3   CNAME   webmail 
brainpad.org
--
4   MX  @   
mail.brainpad.org
(10)
5   A   mail    
199.19.212.38
```

-

I did a test on my domain and those are the results:
e

```
mailtalk.org is getting list of mail servers using k.gtld-servers.net
 'brainpad.org' has 1 mail server

Mail server details
Host Name   IP  Priority
mail.brainpad.org.  199.19.212.38   10


emailtalk.org is now testing mail server configuration


Checking mail.brainpad.org.
Checking PTR record
PTR record exists(node-1j8j1uu.cloud9.ymq1.ca.layeredge.net.) but does not point back to mail.brainpad.org.
A record does not exists for PTR host name

Checking RBL server for blacklisting
Mail server is not black listed
********** Mail server configuration check is complete **********
```

Any idea about what's going on and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your DNS. What are the details of the DSN's? Do you have an MTA installed and running on the server? Is your firewall configured to allow inbound connections to port 25 on the server? Are you able to telnet to port 25 of the server from an external host?

Comment: I can't connect from a remote location, but from local yes. So I guess it's really a firewall problem. I'll look forward to this.

Comment: I created a new rule stating to let inbound connection to port 25 and now I can connect! Let's try the mails :D

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1):

I don't get a response for ping and port 25 from your IP.
Try to connect locally first via `telnet localhost 25` from your server. If that does work, you should check whether your firewall is configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As the output suggests, you don't have a correctly set PTR (pointer) record for mail.brinpad.org.  Your PTR record should resolve 199.19.212.38 to mail.brainpad.org.

Currently a PTR record exists that is resolving 199.19.212.38 to:

node-1j8j1uu.cloud9.ymq1.ca.layeredge.net

It should resolve to mail.brainpad.org

Comment: A missing or invalid PTR record won't stop incoming email.

Comment: Okay, I got this utility. What do I have to change to make it work? http://imgur.com/NPla8 Thx

Comment: It's not a DNS problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty any idea?

Comment: Yes, read my answer and answer those questions. Do you have an email server running on the server? Do you have your firewall configured correctly? Can you make a connection to port 25 of the server using telnet from an external host?

Comment: @joeqwerty When the sending mail server does a DNS lookup on the destination domain isn't it possible that if the PTR record returned is not correct, it could stop delivery? 

Regardless based on tbergeron's other questions I have doubts that this server has a mail server installed.

Comment: No, it's not going to do a PTR lookup at all. It's only doing a forward lookup for the ip address of the A record returned in the MX record.

Comment: PTR is used if the Exchange Server **sends** mails to make sure that the server didn't use a dynamic IP.